# Collecting Tweets using max_id is not working as expected

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

Iam currently doing a tweet search using `Twitter Api`. However, taking the tweet id is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
searchQuery = '#BLM'  # this is what we're searching for
searchQuery = searchQuery + "-filter:retweets"
Geocode="39.8, -95.583068847656, 2500km"    

maxTweets = 1000000 # Some arbitrary large number
tweetsPerQry = 100  # this is the max the API permits
fName = 'tweetsBLM.json' # We'll store the tweets in a json file.

sinceId = None
#max_id = -1 # initial search
max_id=1278836959926980609  # the last id of previous search    
tweetCount = 0
print("Downloading max {0} tweets".format(maxTweets))
with open(fName, 'w') as f:
    while tweetCount < maxTweets:
        try:
            if (max_id <= 0):
                if (not sinceId):
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery,lang="en", geocode=Geocode, 
                                            count=tweetsPerQry)
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery,lang="en",geocode=Geocode,
                                            count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            since_id=sinceId )
            else:
                if (not sinceId):
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, lang="en", geocode=Geocode,
                                            count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1) )
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, lang="en", geocode=Geocode,
                                            count=tweetsPerQry,
                                            max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                            since_id=sinceId)
            if not new_tweets:
                print("No more tweets found")
                break
            for tweet in new_tweets:
                f.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False) +
                        '\n')
            tweetCount += len(new_tweets)
            print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
            max_id = new_tweets[-1].id
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # Just exit if any error
            print("some error : " + str(e))
            print('exception raised, waiting 15 minutes')
            print('(until:', dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(minutes=15), ')')
            time.sleep(15*60)                
            break

print ("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, fName))
```

This code works perfectly fine. I initially run it and got about 40 000 tweets. Then i took the `id` of the `last tweet` of previous/initial search to go back in time. However, i was disappointed to see that there were no tweets anymore. I can not believe that for a second. I must be going wrong somewhere because `#BLM` has been very active in the last 2/3 months.

Any help is very welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the answer. Using `Twitter API`, it is not possible to get older tweets (7 days old or more). Using `max_id` to get around this is not possible either.

The only way is to stream and wait for more than 7 days.

Finally, there is also this link that look for older tweets

https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/ it is an extension of the original Jefferson Henrique's work

Comment: Can you point me to the paragraph in the docs. I do not find it. Thanks